# Typescript function returning two different objects

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, tsconfig, ts-node

I'm fairly new to TypeScript and I'm trying to work out how to get this thing working.
I've done some extensive Googling but have finally resorted to Stack Overflow.

I have a function that returns a User Object or an Error Object, based upon some condition.
When I call this function, I can't seem to handle the different cases without getting the follow error.

```
Property 'error' does not exist on type 'User | Error'.
  Property 'error' does not exist on type 'User'.ts(2339)
```

Here is some code to demonstate my goal, the error occurs at the `>>` in the `main()` funciton.

```
interface User {
    email: string;
    username: string;
}

interface Error {
    error: string;
    code: number;
}

async function get_user_info(user_id: number): Promise<User | Error> {
    const result = await db.get_user(user_id); // let's say this returns false if no user found..
    if (result) {
        const user: User = {
            email: result.email,
            username: result.username
        }
        return user;
    } else {
        const err: Error = {
            error: "Failed to fetch user.",
            code: 583
        }
        return err;
    }
}

async function main() {
    const res = await get_user_info(42);
>>  if (res.error) {
        // handle this...
    } else {
        // continue onwards...
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything, or is this sort of thing just not possible?

Comment: Not an answer, but why do you return a resolved promise containing an error rather than an error promise?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid throwing errors for non fatal events to improve performance.. figured it was better to return as normal and handle the non fatal error based upon the return value.

Comment: Hi @Latchy, I had the same kind of problem, but in my case I wanted to type the response of a wrapper function for a 'POST' request using Fetch API. The response body could either be a user object, like { id: number, name: string, email: string }, or an error object, { error: { email: string, password: string } }. I had the same problem when testing "res.error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a type guard that tests if it is an `User` or an `Error` object by checking if the `error` property exists:

```ts
async function main() {

    const res = await get_user_info(42);

    if ('error' in res) {
         if (res.error) {
             // handle this...
         }
    } else {
        // continue onwards...
    }
}
```